# How to tell a user a menu is a page or not

Tags: input

I'm developing a CMS, which its hierarchical menu/navigation is *a combination between pages and tree menu*, just like code below:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="page.php?id=1">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="page.php?id=2">Plumbing</a></li>
        <li><a href="page.php?id=3">Decoration</a></li>
        <li><a href="page.php?id=4">Demolition</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="page.php?id=5">Clients</li>
  <li><a href="page.php?id=6">Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Because the menu changes from time to time (as the user/admin would like to add or delete menus). So far, if a user/admin add a menu I'm using this HTML code below:

```
Menu name: <input class="text" name="menu_name">
If this a page, please include this page link, or let it empty if it's not a page:
<input class="text" name="page_link">
```

Is this the best solution?

A note: users/admins are not very Internet/computer savvy. No working knowledge using CMS like Wordpress before. I'm also afraid they don't know how to copy link text from browser :)

Comment: This question could use a little more context? You call it a website, but users are adding and removing menu items? What's the reason users can  do this?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not clear about this. What I'm building is a CMS, and there are some users who has administrative rights to change website's layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not going to help with the coding, but I will help you with the design. 
So if you want, user to add menu or delete it the first thing user must be known what are the menus are present so as to avoid duplicate.

You can make it in this way: (Refer image)
[image: sample image for design of answer]

Image is just for design purpose. After adding done, ask user to rearrange the whole menu in case he needs it. That will be a good user experiance. And if possible ask user to add multiple menus.

Comment: Thank you for this. I've just edited my question, so would you be kind to simplify these inputs to more less-savvy users?

Comment: For less savvy users, we can put a tooltip demonstarting what to fill in this feild, if that would be fine for you. Or remove link icon and write link-to text.